# Function polymorphism. Return B as A is null when A:B

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

How can I do something like the following?
My `A` object is null after calling `GetB` even though `A` inherits from `B`.

```
class Program
{
    public class A : B
    {
    }

    public class B
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = GetB() as A;
        Console.WriteLine(a == null); // it is null!

        Console.WriteLine("Console.ReadKey();");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static B GetB()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: class C : B { }. Is C an A? Obviously not. How could it be? Why do you think, then, that you should be able to cast *any* B to A? A inherits B, not the other way around. A is a B, that much is clear. B? It might be C. D. Or maybe it's just plain old B.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram see my answer below, we think too much alike...

Comment: error is [more pronounced](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FailFast) if you do old style of casting. i.e. `A a = (A)GetB()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to downcast your B into an A. You can't do that, nor does it makes sense because we do not know if a B is going to be an A. It would be better to build a constructor in your `A` class that takes a `B` as a parameter.

```
public class A : B
{
    public A(B b)
    {
        //perform your conversion of a B into an A
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B(){}
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    B b = new B();
    A a = new A(b);
    Console.WriteLine(a == null); // it is null!

    Console.WriteLine("Console.ReadKey();");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably meant `return new A();` in the function. At the moment, you're trying to down-cast your `B` to an `A`, which won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You got it reversed:

```
class Program
{
    public class A : B  // should be: public class A
    {
    }

    public class B // should be: public class B : A
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // If you reverse the inheritance on code above
        // As Ben Voigt noticed, *as A* is redundant. should be removed
        // A a = GetB() as A; 

        // should be this. B is wider than A, so A can accept B, no need to cast
        A a = GetB(); 
        Console.WriteLine(a == null); // it is null!

        Console.WriteLine("Console.ReadKey();");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static B GetB()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't need `as` at all in this case.

Comment: I copy pasted his code and highlighted the main cause of error

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to perform this type of casting, because `B` very well may not be an `A`! Sure, `A` is a subclass of `B`, so you could always perform a `GetA() as B;`. But going the other way doesn't make sense; most likely an instance of `A` provides some additional functionality over an instance of `B`.

Consider adding a third class, `C : B`. What if your function `GetB()` actually returned a `new C()`? This is fine, since `C` is a `B`. But certainly you wouldn't want to be able to cast this to an `A`? `A` and `C` would almost certainly have little in common.